# Retriving Subarrays PHP

Tags: php, sql, search, arrays

I have a database which has 6 column A B C D E X, for each combination of ABCDE I have a different value of X.

I need a way to search through, that will allow all values of X for different combinations (for example all X when A=1, or all X when A=1 and B=2 etc)

My thought was to translate it into a 5-D array which looks like this:

```
Array[A][B][C][D][E]=X;
```

But now I'm trying to extract sub arrays, when I don't know how may of the dimensions will be constant. So I need to be able to extract all value of X for `Array[1][5][][][]` or `Array[2][4][5][][]`… etc.

And I'm totally stuck.

I'm trying to do 6 loops one inside another but I don't know how to handle those that are constant.

Help with ideas will be very very helpful.

**Edit**

```
Database:
A B C D E X
1 1 1 1 1 53
1 1 2 3 2 34
2 1 1 4 2 64
```

Turned it into an array:

```
Array[1][1][1][1][1]=53
Array[1][1][2][3][2]=34
```

For

```
Input: A=1
Output 53,34
Input A=1,B=1,C=1
Output: 53,
```

etc

Comment: i need to see an example of the data and desired outcome to understand this one

Comment: i dont know what you need Jake, but i believe its just love :-)

Comment: Just change your query: `SELECT x FROM table WHERE a = ?, b= ?` etc

Comment: Please see comment to Tantos bellow

Comment: Wow you guys are really mean - I know you can do this through SQL, but I wanted a different approach checked. Thank you for editing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this then

```
<?php
$arr = array();
$result = mysql_query("SELECT A,B,C,D,E,X FROM table_name ORDER BY A ASC,B ASC,C ASC,D ASC,E ASC");
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        array_push($arr,$row);
    }
}

function search($arr,$values) {
    $return = array();
    foreach($arr AS $key => $value) {
        $ok = true;
        foreach(array('A','B','C','D','E') AS $letter) {
            if(array_key_exists($letter,$values)) {
                if($value[$letter] != $values[$letter]) {
                    $ok = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if($ok) array_push($return,$value['X']);
    }
    return (($return) ? implode(',',$return) : false);
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r(search($arr,array('A' => 1)));
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Comment: Thank you Tanatos, the thing is it is going to be done rapidly and I don't want to connect to the database each time. I was hoping to get all the data and just retrive the parts I need

Comment: Thank you Tanatos, this makes perfect sence!